# How to create a fully responsive image (not just width:100% and height: auto)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

to train my web dev skills, I clone some pages, but everytime there is a huge image, I can't make it fully responsive, it look destroyed on phone or when you reduce the screen size.
Today I'm cloning this page :

https://500px.com/

As you can see this site is fully fully responsive, I mean if I reduce the page anyway it will be "ok".
Particulary the first big image with the couple on a mountain, even the text in is responsive!

Here is my code:

```js
<!-- Jquery qui fait que le header devient blanc quand on scroll -->
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
        $("header").addClass("active");
    } else {
        //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
       $("header").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 
}

header {
width: 100%;
height:40px;
background-color: transparent;
position: fixed;

}

.active { background-color: white;}

.all {
 display: flex;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.po {
 padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}
.pa {
 padding: 0 50px 0 0px;
}
.pi {
 padding: 0 50px 0 0;
 }
.home {
 
 width: 100%;
}
.hm {
 width:100%;
 margin-top: -200px;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-height: 1000px;
 min-width: 1000px;
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 

   width: 100%; 
   text-align: center;
}
h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px; 
   font-size: 40px; 

   padding: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="px"> 500px </div>
    <div class="po"> Community </div>
    <div class="pa"> MarketPlace </div>
    <div class="pi"> Log in </div>
    <div class="pu"> Sign Up </div>
  </div>
</header>


<div class="home">
  <img class="hm" src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/R6ZWbAb.jpg"  >
  <h2><span> Home to everyone best photos </span></h2>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m85ppaxs/)

But the image isn't responsive like the website. If I reduce it too much, the text and the image will

So here are my two questions :
Do they used Jquery/bootstrap/javascript to make their first big image responsive?
If yes can you lead me to some tutotial or try to explain?
If no how they done that?

Comment: You might want to take a look at bootstrap's responsive images. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images basically the image will scale with the parent element

Comment: Just looking a the DOM for 500px.com, I can see that they are using javascript, not CSS to resize the images because the width for each image is inlined via `style` attribute.

Comment: @styfle the JS on individual image pages is used to vertically center the image.

Comment: Please include all relevant code *in the question itself*, not on jsfiddle. We have a rule about that, which you've gotten around by putting "enter code here" in your question. Is it really that hard to copy and paste?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm sorry for that, i'm not use to it, and I've cheated to post this one, I won't do that again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need for jQuery or Javascript, in this case, just plain CSS will do the trick. Instead of using an `img` element we will use a `div` and place the image as a background image.

The following would be the html that should replace your img element;

```
<div class="responsive_img">

</div>
```

And this would be your CSS;

```
.responsive_img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/R6ZWbAb.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Here's a simplified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgnk6cxk/) that does what you want, and here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m85ppaxs/1/) of how you would implement this into your current demo.

There are probably ways of doing this with any of the languages you mentioned in your question, but this is probably the simplest.

Comment: Thank's, this work as intended, you've explain it well, have a nice day/night!